# Validating apple pay payment token signature

Tags: node.js, openssl, applepay

For some reasons, I have to process apple pay payment token without a payment platform. According to [official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014929), I need to "**verify the signature**" first. And the signature is a detached PKCS #7 signature in base64 encoding. I wanted to validate it with node.js or openssl.

<s>Since node-forge, a very handy crypto tool, doesn't support "ECDSA with sha256" yet ([link](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/532)), and I can't find other replacement. I turned to openssl. With some investigation, It seems the signature is packaged in "**CMS signed data**" format. So I found this command from openssl manual should be able to do the job:</s>

> openssl cms -verify -inform DER -in signature.der -content content.txt

Apple document says "**ensure that the signature is a valid ECDSA signature of the concatenated values of the ephemeralPublicKey, data, transactionId, and applicationData keys**". So I generate my test content by concating those fields from my test token. But the result is:

```
Verification failure
C0:25:34:08:01:00:00:00:error:CMS routines:CMS_SignerInfo_verify_content:verification failure:crypto/cms/cms_sd.c:901:
C0:25:34:08:01:00:00:00:error:CMS routines:CMS_verify:content verify error:crypto/cms/cms_smime.c:399:
```

cms_sd.c:901 is signer verifying the igest so I think this command is what I need. Then what I did wrong?

**Update**: I found that [PKI.js](https://pkijs.org/) can do the job. Detailed answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet below from [PKI.js example](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/blob/master/examples/CMSSignedComplexExample/es6.js#L844) shows how to parse an existing CMSSignedData.

```
const testData = "<TOKEN_SIGNATURE>";

const cmsSignedBuffer = stringToArrayBuffer(fromBase64(testData));
const asn1 = asn1js.fromBER(cmsSignedBuffer);
const cmsContentSimpl = new ContentInfo({ schema: asn1.result });
const cmsSignedSimpl = new SignedData({ schema: cmsContentSimpl.content });
```

After this, we can extract the certificates and signer information for further process.

**check OIDs**:

```
cmsSignedSimpl.certificates[0].extensions.find(x => x.extnID === '1.2.840.113635.100.6.29') // leaf certificate
cmsSignedSimpl.certificates[1].extensions.find(x => x.extnID === '1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.14') // intermediate certificate
```

**verify signature and chain of trust**:

```
cmsSignedSimpl.verify({
    signer: 0,
    trustedCerts: [AppleRootCA_G3],
    data: signedData,
    checkChain: true, // check x509 chain of trust
    extendedMode: true, // enable to show signature validation result
  });
```

**check singing time**:

```
const attrs = cmsSignedSimpl.signerInfos[0].signedAttrs.attributes;
const signingTimeAttr = attrs.find(x => x.type === '1.2.840.113549.1.9.5');
const signingTime = new Date(signingTimeAttr.value[0].toDate());
```